# Get data from getter method instead of passing in a Bundle

Tags: java, android, bundle

I need to pass some Bitmaps from one activity to another, and, since the size limit of the Bundle won't let me pass these images (even using a byte array*), I thought that I could use a getter method between these Activities.

-But, since I'm still not a master in Android (Java), **I don't know if that would make any difference**, and, if it does, **what should I watch out for when using it.**

**the byte array did reduce the total size(at about 60%), but it still wasn't enough**

**scaling down is a way out, but just in case any other solution works**

Comment: If the images are saved in the `External Storage` you can just pass the `URI` through intent and get the bitmap through uri

Comment: I'm not saving the images neither getting them from the app folder. They are being downloaded each time the app runs.

Comment: The safest way will be to save those images in a temp folder in you internal storage. make `URI` for them and pass the `URI` to next activity. Passing stream of data through activities may cause your app to break if exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks!! Will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your object in a file

```
    private void saveDataToFile() {

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = getContext().openFileOutput("fileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {

}
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
try {
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {

}
try {
    if (objectOutputStream != null) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(yourObject); //which data u want to save
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    if (objectOutputStream != null) {
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Retrieve the object from another activity

```
private void getDataFromFile() {

FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = getContext().openFileInput("fileName");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
try {
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
} catch (IOException |NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    yourObject = (ObjectClass) objectInputStream.readObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    objectInputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: Haven't thought about saving in cache, thanks!
But why wouldn't the getter through class work?

Comment: because when we getter u need to create an object of the class. when we create an object all of its members initially null. creating an object of an activity is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Pass through Uri by writing getter method in POJO class

Comment: I'm not saving the images neither getting them from the app folder. They are being downloaded each time the app runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getter setter, just create URI of your bitmap and pass to setter method in POJO class and then retrieve using getter method of POJO class.

Comment: I'm not saving the images neither getting them from the app folder. They are being downloaded each time the app runs.